# Лингвозадача на ваше воображение (лабильные переходно-непереходные глаголы в русском языке)

Tags: глаголы

В английском языке существуют глаголы, которые являются и переходными и непереходными, при этом в своем непереходном варианте они обозначают то же самое действие как и в переходном, только субъект действия является и объектом. Вот пара примеров:

```
The door opened (by itself) // Дверь открылась
I opened the door. // Я открыл дверь

The water boiled (by itself) // Вода кипела (кипятилась)
I boiled the water. // Я кипятил (вскипятил) воду
```

Видим, что в русском языке используются разные глаголы (возвратный с -ся для непереходной формы и без -ся для переходной). В то время как в английском используется один и тот же глагол, и поэтому он и называется лабильный.

А теперь задача: приведите пример лабильного, переходно-непереходного глагола в русском языке.

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj6kuCWmc7-AhWQQ_EDHaUSDzIQFnoECA8QAw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.dialog-21.ru%2Fdigests%2Fdialog2006%2Fmaterials%2Fhtml%2FLetuchy.htm&usg=AOvVaw1Kw3rsDy8dYyh4KuALgrt5 Здесь подробно об этом написано.

Comment: Класс, в этой статье полный список. Осторожно спойлеры.